# How do I ready this registry?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, registry

I'm trying to read this registry:

> HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MYXMLfile\Shell\Open\Command

from C#, using this code:

```
Registry.ClassesRoot.GetValue(@"MYXMLfile\Shell\Open\Command", "not found")
```

But it returns always:

> not found

What am I missing?

the application is already running as administrator.

**UPDATE:**

I've tried opening the key too:

```
const string keyName = @"MYXMLfile\Shell\Open";
using (var key = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(keyName, false))
{
    var val = (string) key.GetValue("Command"); // return null
}
```

**UPDATE2:**

I've tried set `RegistryView` since it's a 32bit app running on 64bit OS but still doesn't work. Code:

```
 string keyName = @"MYXMLfile\Shell\Open";
        RegistryView regView = Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem ? RegistryView.Registry64 : RegistryView.Registry32;
        using (var baseKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.ClassesRoot, regView))
        using(var key = baseKey.OpenSubKey(keyName))
        {
            var v = key.GetValue("Command"); // null
        }
```

Comment: You have to open the key first and then read the value you want. Check out the example code here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9f66s0a(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @itsme86: Check out my edit, I've already tried this and give same result...

Comment: The subkey is the whole path down to the value. i.e. if it's in the left pane of regedit, it's part of the key. There should be no backslashes in `GetValue()`.

Comment: Perhaps an issue with 32/64bit? Are you running as x86? If you are, it will be looking at the Wow6432Node I believe.

Comment: I'm on x64 based system. The writing is fine, I'm created that key by code, the issue is on reading. Any ideas?

Comment: but the executable is 32bit. Is thing going to be an issue when reading from regedit?

Comment: I deleted my answer since i think if everything you tried isnt working, you either have not created that entry, or you have some error, i cannot reproduce. (Typo mostly on creation)

Comment: Looking at your 2nd update I think your logic is wrong. It doesn't matter if it's a 64-bit OS or not. Your application needs to know if it itself is 32-bit. Did you try just hardcoding it to look at the 32-bit registry?

Comment: @lokusking: I did created it, they key is there. I checked several types. If I do I right mouse click on it -> copy key name I get exactly the key I put in the question: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MYXMLfile\Shell\Open\Command`

Comment: @TyCobb: I didn't hard coded anything, that 2nd update was just a attempt to retrieve the value which is already there. I did some research that pointe out that reading registry from a 32bit application on 64bit system would need to use `RegistryView` so I tried it. Didn't worked either way